# Starting a Windows Service programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a quartz.NET project set up which should schedule a windows service to run every so often. Currently, I am trying to start the service like this:

```
Process.Start("path/app.exe");
```

But I'm getting: "Cannot start a service from the command line or a debugger. A Windows Service must first be installed and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Admin tool, or the NET START command.

So I'm wondering, first of all, will this go away in release mode? Or am I going to have to find another way to go about this. Either way, I need to be able to schedule this job programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message tells you a few ways how to start the service, but those are not the right way to do it from C#. There is a better way: Use the `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` class to start the service.